# how do I attach child structs data to a parent struct?

Tags: c, struct, nested

I have an issue with nested structs for a pretty complex assignment (in my opinion):

I don't know how to ensure the child struct data is added to the parent struct

I've been getting a blank in everything and used Valgrind and GDB to help with the segmentation faults.  Once I get to the `my_input` function below the `struct` has no data

```
/*declaration*/

struct grandparent
{
  struct parent dad;
}

struct parent
{
 struct child a;
 struct child b;
}

struct child
{
  child name first;
}
```

from these I create a menu which according to gdb hold the correct info at the end of the function (it is not a pointer in the function arguments):

```c
void init_child(struct child children[])
{
  /*other code....*/
  funcPtr[0] = another_function; /* a list of function pointers follows*/
  for(i = 0; i< ITEMS; ++i)
  {  
    *child[i].name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*)*strlen(names[i])+1);
    strcpy(child[count].name, names[i]);
    child[i]function = funcPtr[i];
  }
```

the malloc I've used is the only way I can get it without crashing straight away

from this I need to use a function that only accepts the grandparent data:
and runs the corresponding function from the menu:

```c
void my_input(struct grandparent* grandad)
{
  struct child *temp = grandad->dad.child;
  /*other code*/
  for(i=0; i<ITEMS; ++1)
  {
    printf("\n%d) %s", i+1, temp[i].name);
  }
```

this prints the numbers, but nothing for the names I then get code to obtain the input, which is the correct input.

I then try to run

```c
temp[menu_choice].function(grandad);
```

this gives me the segmentation error

from using Valgrind and GDB I can see that there is no data being given to struct child *temp, so I believe that there is a step missing to connect the data to the parent and the grandparents.  Of course, I could be completely incorrect also.

If any of this makes sense and you have any suggestions they would be welcome

Comment: Are the struct declarations in that order without the compiler complaining? I'd expect them to be child, used in parent, used in grandparent... Please make a [mcve].

Comment: Considering `strcpy(child[count].name, ...)` then `*child[i].name = malloc(...)` is probably not correct. You don't get a warning for that? Then you should probably enable more verbose warnings.

Comment: If the compiler does not complain about `child name first;` then there is more hidden than you show.

Comment: As it's an assignment I've tried to dumb it down, probably too much to be honest

Comment: You know, a grandparent is also a child and a parent. Are you required to have different structs? I would expect to have structs to describe a person used for alle involved people and the role as child, parent etc. should be defined by the way they are linked.